# Sending data using asyncore doesn't work

Tags: python, asyncore

I made this basic client to accommodate myself with asyncore.

```
import asyncore, socket

class TestClient(asyncore.dispatcher):
    def __init__(self, host, port):
        asyncore.dispatcher.__init__(self)
        self.create_socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connect((host, port))
        self.buffer = "madonna"

        def handle_connect(self):
            pass

        def handle_close(self):
            print "Close"
            self.close()

        def handle_read(self):
            print self.recv(8192)

        def writable(self):
            print "Calling writable"
            return (len(self.buffer) > 0)

        def handle_write(self):
            print "Write"
            sent = self.send(self.buffer)
            self.buffer = self.buffer[sent:]

client = TestClient("127.0.0.1", 7899)
asyncore.loop()
```

I think I am not doing something right. I can connect to the server but it doesn't send any data. Because the `buffer` is not empty, shouldn't Writable be called to check the buffer and if is not empty call `handle_write` ?

Besides the `__init__` method, nothing gets called.

Comment: Can it be a simple indentation problem? All your methods are into the `__init__` scope.

Comment: How could I missed that ? You can provide this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Done. Glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should re-indent your methods :)